# onResume no funciona cuando genero el apk, pero si funciona si la app es instalada desde Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo una duda, estoy trabajando en una aplicación desarrollada en Android Studio, la cual cuando la instalo en mi teléfono desde Android Studio, no genera ningún problema, pero cuando genero el apk y la instalo igualmente en mi teléfono (Huawei con Android 6.0) general el problema que cuando me salgo de la aplicación y luego vuelvo acceder, la sesión muere y me vuelve a tirar el login, lo cual no es el comportamiento esperado, se espera que al salir de la aplicación y al acceder unos segundos después la sesión siga activa. Y lo extraño es que este problema solo pasa cuando genero la app, si la aplicación la instalo desde Android Studio no sucede, alguna idea de que puede pasar?

Comment: Agrega el código del método `onResume ()` para que podamos ayudarte y también te recomiendo incluir el nivel de la API del emulador en Android Studio que utilizas para ejecutar la app desde ahí.

Comment: Esto no tiene sentido, no creo que exista una diferencia al llamar el método te sugiero agregar más información